# Cálculo vetorial C++

Tags: c++, matriz, matemática, geometria

Preciso implementar algumas operações vetoriais e matriciais, tais como o produto interno, vetorial, outras operações com matrizes (cálculo da inversa, transposta, conjugada, determinante, etc) e de resolver certos problemas de álgebra linear e geometria analítica... Consigo fazer isso tudo à unha mas queria arranjar alguma library que implementasse isso de forma mais limpa. Obrigado!

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque se trata de uma pergunta de lista.

Answer (score 2):

Há o [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) e o [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). Vê também as "Numerical Recipes in C++" [aqui](http://numerical.recipes/), um clássico da análise numérica computacional que qualquer cientista ou engenheiro devia ler.